# How to delegate more tezos to the same baker?

Tags: delegating

I delegated some tezos to a given baker for first time some days ago. This created a KT address. If I want to delegate more tezos to the same baker, do I simply send tezos to that KT address? Thus, if I have several delegations, to add further funds, do I just send to the respective KT address? In this sense, is the KT address a sort of contract between the baker and a given wallet?

I've seen many posts on how to delegate for the first time (e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@PosBakerz/how-to-delegate-your-tezos-using-pos-bakerz-d1a2a36c267c)) but is unclear how to delegate further to the same baker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume you have some tz1X address from which you originated two contracts KT1X and KT1Y, and assume you delegated KT1X to some baker A and the contract KT1Y to another baker B.

If you want to delegate more tezzies to A, you can just send more tokens to your KT1X contract.